# Assigning multiple keys for OrbitContorls in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to assign **multiple keys** for **an event**. (E.g. pressing [a] or [<-] do the same event.) I already had checked the [OrbitControls Docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.enablePan) and 
[Keyboard Event Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

I know `65` is 'A' and `37` is '<-', so **I was expecting something like below**. However, I couldn't find the right way *(other than adding another `eventHander`)* to assign both keys to a single event.

```
controls.key = {LEFT: [36, 65], UP: ... }
or
controls.key = {LEFT: 36 || 65, UP: ... }
```

Reference Doc (OrbitControls of Three.js)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not supported by `OrbitControls`. You can only assign a single value to `LEFT`, `UP`, `RIGHT`, `BOTTOM`. If you want a different behavior, you have to modify the class.

However, doing so should not be complicated since the only function you have to modify is `handleKeyDown()`. That's the place where `event.keyCode` is evaluated.

`three.js R107`